# Is it possible to have a conditional third expression in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'd like to know whether the third argument (statement/expression?) in a for loop can be conditional. For example, if a function were to be invoked with an optional third argument, the presence or absence of this optional argument would determine the third operation.

```
function doThing(arg1, arg2, optional) {
    var args = arguments;
    for (var i = arg1; arg1 < arg2; args[2] ? i = i+optional : i++) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I can't find anything relating to this online, so I'm guessing probably not; if not what would be the best way to create the same functionality?

Comment: Does your `optional` variable determine how many steps to increment `i`?

Comment: @showdev - in this example yes, sorry that wasn't made clear. But it wouldn't necessarily have to I suppose.

Comment: Why the mixed syntax of using named arguments and also using `args[2]`? Why not just use one or the other?

Comment: @TedHopp Only because I read that `arguments` doesn't always behave like an array, whereas storing them in an array and acting on those yields more reliable results. But you could probably put it down to inexperience more than anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.3

```
IterationStatement : for ( ExpressionNoIn opt ; Expression opt ; Expression opt ) Statement
```

You can see that the third argument for `for` is an expression. So anything that is a valid expression can be used there.

`args[2] ? i = i+optional : i++` is a valid expression.

I'd rather specify it as:

```
i += args[2] ? optional : 1
```

Comment: Difficult to choose an answer, given the many useful suggestions, but I'm accepting this as it directly addresses the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
var step = (optional === undefined ? 1 : optional);
for (var i = arg1; i < arg2; i += step) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can always rewrite the `for` loop by leaving out the increment and manually handling it inside the loop:

```
for (var i = arg1; arg1 < arg2; ) {
    // Do stuff

    if (condition) {
        i = i + optional;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Your case, however, can be simplified rewritten as:

```
for (var i = arg1; arg1 < arg2; i += (condition ? optional : 1))
```

If the logic is more complex then simple increment, then using the first example would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, but it would require re-evaluating `args[2]` on every iteration, which can be a bit inefficient. I'd recommend a slightly different alternative:

```
function doThing(arg1, arg2, optional) {
    var inc = optional || 1;
    for (var i = arg1; arg1 < arg2; i += inc ) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

This way you've only have to determine the `inc` value (how much to increment `i` by in the loop) once, then you can reuse that value throughout the rest of the function.

Comment: @verism Yes, sorry. That was a typo.